# Predicting products of a reaction and balancing

Tags: reaction-mechanism, solubility, synthesis

2BiOCl + NaOH = BiOH + NaCl.
This is the reaction where I am trying to get Bismuth Hydroxide as one product and salt. My problem is what is the state of Bismuth Hydroxide? Whether it is BiOH or Bi (OH)2 or Bi(OH)3. How do I know which one I will get?

Comment: You know that from the valence of Bi, and that you deduce by looking at BiOCl.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the reaction actually produces $\ce{BiO.OH}$. According to [this site:](http://bismuth.atomistry.com/bismuth_oxychloride.html)

> It reacts with alkalis, especially when the solutions are
>   concentrated. It is probable that with a dilute solution of potassium
>   hydroxide a reversible reaction takes place according to the equation
>
> $$\ce{BiOCl + KOH <=> BiO.OH + KCl}$$
>
> With concentrated solutions the action is much more complex.

Some sources states that the reaction produces Bismuth(III) oxide. In conclusion, the reaction may produces different species depending on concentration of alkali, reaction conditions, amount of bismuth oxychloride etc.